# How to check if obj is of type luxon?

Tags: luxon

I am writing a date adapter for Angular Material, and need a function that returns a boolean if the provided object is a luxon DateTime.

Something like this (from moment):

```
isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    return moment.isMoment(obj);
  }
```

What I have is this so far - is this good enough?:

```
isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
      try {
          const luxonObject = DateTime.fromObject(obj);
          return luxonObject.isValid;
      } catch (error) {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that your code is fine, I would suggest that you can use native [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

function isDateInstance(obj) {
    return obj instanceof DateTime;
}

console.log( isDateInstance('') );
console.log( isDateInstance({}) );
console.log( isDateInstance(new Date()) );
console.log( isDateInstance(DateTime.local()) );
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

Luxon has added [`isDateTime`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeisdatetime) method in `v.1.6.0` that

> Check if an object is a DateTime. Works across context boundaries

so an updated solution can be the following:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

function isDateInstance(obj) {
    return DateTime.isDateTime(obj);
}

console.log( isDateInstance('') );
console.log( isDateInstance({}) );
console.log( isDateInstance(new Date()) );
console.log( isDateInstance(DateTime.local()) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.10.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

From `v.1.6.0` until `v.1.8.3` `isDateTime` will give `undefined` instead of `false` due to an [issue](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/376).